# Fire GWT event in webdriver?? Possible or not?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, selenium

I have a GWT QueryEditor widget that generates the below HTML on typing "select 1" in a text-area look-alike sub-widget. :

```
<div id='editor'>
  <pre>
    <span class='keyword'>select</span>
    <span class='number'>1</span>
  </pre>
</div>
```

On every keyPress, a GWT event is fired that validates the query.

I have to test the above scenario using WebDrivers.

I tried to use sendKeys on the `<pre>` tag but it didn't work. (`<pre>` tag cannot get focus).

So I used the JavaScriptExecutor to set the innerHTML of the `<pre>` tag and I can see the text in the test - browser. However, the query doesn't get validated as the keyUp/onChange events are not fired by javaScriptExecutor. This causes my test to fail.

How can I fire these backend GWT events via web-drivers?

Any help would be really appreciated... And please let me know if I need to make my question more clear...

Thanks.